# Calling Bash commands from Ruby and returning output?

Tags: ruby

The following code includes a command and a string:

```
files = `ls /tmp`
```

I would like `/tmp` to be a variable instead of a static string, and would ideally like it to be like:

```
dir = '/tmp'
command = 'ls ' + dir
files = `command`
```

What is the correct Ruby syntax to achieve this?

Comment: I hope this shouldn't need saying, but be VERY careful about accepting user input if you're going to execute it blindly in a shell

Comment: There are some great examples using  string interpolation in [this great card](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1243-execution-of-shell-code-in-ruby-scripts) I've been recommended yesterday.

Comment: thanks folks, shall do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string interpolation:

```
dir   = '/tmp'
files = `ls #{dir}`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
files = `#{command}`
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard [*shellwords*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/index.html) library.  It will take care of proper escaping, which will help to protect you from shell injection attacks.

```
require 'shellwords'

command = [
  'ls',
  dir
].shelljoin
files = `#{command}`
```

If *dir* comes from untrusted input, the above code still allows someone to see any directory on your system.  However, using shelljoin protects you from someone injecting, for example, a "delete all files on my hard drive" command.

In the particular case of listing a directory, The built-in class [*Dir*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html) will do that rather well:

```
files = Dir[File.join(dir, '*')]
```

Here we add a glob onto the end of the directory using [File::join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-join).  [Dir::[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) then returns the paths of the files in that directory.